# How to use SIGN IN WITH Facebook button in android?

Tags: android, facebook, sign

I want to use a Sign In with Facebook button which will allow users to use my android app with his/her facebook credential.

I am trying to search for a step by step guide to do this. Is there any good reference and tutorial to do so ? And can it be achieved without using facebook android SDK ?

I wanted to know if there are any other ways achieve that because I don't want to use different SDK or libraries for other Social Network integration.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ .This is the best tutorial that you will ever got.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook explains how to do thi with the SDK.
Why are you trying to do it without the SDK? They've done most of the work for you!